# Why is reaction.message undefined?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Why is `reaction.message` not defined? I have guild in other files and it work fine. Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined`. And the error is here: `message.guild.channels`

```
module.exports = (client, Discord, chalk, message, args) => {
    const channelId = '799339037306912808'
  
    const getEmoji = (emojiName) =>
      client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === emojiName)
  
    const emojis = {
      golden_ticket: 'rules',
    }
  
    const handleReaction = (reaction, user, add) => {
      if (user.id === '799652033509457940') {
        return
      }
  
      const emoji = reaction._emoji.name
  
      const { guild } = reaction.message
  
      const userName = user.username
      const userId = guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id)
      const categoryId = '802172599836213258';
  
      if (add) {
        reaction.users.remove(userId)
        message.guild.channels
        .create(`${userName}`, {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                    id: userId
                }
            ],
        })
        .then((channel) => {
            channel.setParent(categoryId)
        })
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  
    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
      if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
        handleReaction(reaction, user, true)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: The error does *not* mean that `guild` is undefined. It means that `message` is undefined.

Comment: FYI `TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined` doesn't mean `guild` is undefined but that `message` is.

Comment: @Dominik not `reaction.message`, but `message.guild`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox it looks like it's coming from this line: `const { guild } = reaction.message`

Comment: `message.guild.channels` seems weird because you already have `guild` further up so you should be able to use just `guild.channels` instead. Alternatively, `reaction.message.guild.channel` should work, too.

Comment: @Dominik That's not what OP says

Comment: @Dominik I thought so too, but the question says "And the error is here: `message.guild.channels`"

Comment: Right.. now I see it. :)

Comment: I don't know why, but `reaction.message.guild.channel` is working.